# How to get Android Studio to recognize DoD ssl certificates

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use a government api (`https://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=8/8/2019&coords=48.39,-115.56&tz=-7`) to get sunrise and sunset type information and I get the error `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`. I was having the same problems using the Chrome browser on Windows 10 until I imported the government certificates.

However, I can not figure out how to get the Android Studio emulator to recognize the certs (I will worry about my Nexus 6 device after I get everything working in the emulator).

I have a file of the government certs and have added them to Android Studio using `Settings/tools/ServerCertificates`.  The certs I have added are DOD ID SW CA-38, DoD Root CA 2, DoD Root CA 3, and DoD Root CA 4.  When I look at the certificate path on the browser, it shows DoD Root CA 3, DOD ID SW CA-38 and `api.usno.navy.mil`.  The `api.usno.navy.mil` cert was issued by DOD ID SW CA-38.

I have tried setting the Server Certificates to "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" (not my favorite option).

All were no help. I have also looked through the stackoverflow messages that seem related and did not find a solution.  I am trying to not use third party apps.

Although it was not apparently needed in the browser, could there be some other certificate specifically for the `api.usno.navy.mil` reference?

The usno (U.S. Naval Observatory) has requested certificates that are more generally acknowledged (versus the DoD certificates), but they don't know when the administrators will provide them.

How can I get the Android Studio emulator to recognize these DoD certificates?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Complete stack trace follows:

```
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):47)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.drme.weatherNoaa.NetworkHelpers.getUrlBytes(NetworkHelpers.java:123)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.drme.weatherNoaa.SunMoonWebRunnable.run(SunMoonWebRunnable.java:108)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):2)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):1)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):5)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):8)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):15)
4424-4451/com.drme.weathertest W/System.err:    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Where exactly did you find this domain? ICANN doesn't recognize the full domain, and each parent domain level doesn't exist.

Comment: I found the indicated api on `https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/api.php` when looking for Sunset and Sunrise information on the web.  This site contains directions on using the api.  These are sites use government/DoD certs that are not usually found in the "civilian" Certificate Authorities. They are working on getting more "normal" certificates, but don't have them yet.  I am currently trying to track down a separate cert for the 'api.usno.navy.mil` address.